# Creating Forms In a ForEach - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with an array in PHP. For each thing in the array, I want to create a form and button attached to it. In addition to that, an action when the button is pushed. I fear it may have something to do with timing or such.

Here is my code:

```
foreach($projects as $proj){
echo "<form action='post'><input type='button' name='forminput' Value ='Yup'></form>";
$name = $_POST['forminput'];
}

if($name){
echo "ye";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: place Form  tag above the loop, and place input controls inside loop

Comment: Appreciate the quick response @user1844933 - can you elaborate? I am afraid I don't understand.

Comment: so if you have 100 variables in your array you want 100 forms each with 100 buttons to submit the form?

Comment: Yes spot on @niels!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php

$arrayName = array('test1' => '1', 'test2' => '2', 'test3' => '3', 'test4' => '4');

foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {
  $$key = $value;
  echo '
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="forminput" Value ="'.$$key.'">
  </form>
  ';
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$key = strip_tags($key); // to prevent scripts being injected into the page
$value = strip_tags($value);

  echo $key . ' ' . $value;
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Incredible! Works like a champion!